# Unable to get user email, as a result of this i am getting NullPointer

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

My profileActivity wont start due to getting a NullPointer exception, I assume the problem is with

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome " + user.getEmail());`
```

and that email is Null but I cant understand why.
Here is my code:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
```

inside `onCreate`:

```
textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);

firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
}

FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome " + user.getEmail());
```

Here is the log error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.liamthedeveloper.foodiez/com.liamthedeveloper.foodiez.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.liamthedeveloper.foodiez.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:66)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: whats your 66th line of the the activity ?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference`   -> This is the problem. It seems `user` is `null`.

Comment: @Sahil my 66th line is textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome " + user.getEmail());

Comment: We have a standard Q&A on this subject: [What is a NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/812149). You may be interested in reading it.

Comment: i think you have not logged in with google that is why it is null. user is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();

String name = user.getDisplayName();
```

Then add this check to avoid `NullPointerException`

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
    textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome " + user.getEmail());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference
```

It is clearly that the object of FirebaseUser is null,it means that the user in your code is null, not the email is null.

Comment: how is this the case if it is set to 'FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();'

Comment: maybe firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() return a null, how can u confim user != null?

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink your null check of the Firebase user object.

```
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
}
```

This will not stop the execution of `onCreate`, hence you will invoke a method on a null reference.

Make sure to stop the execution in your null check, i.e :

```
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
    return;
}
```

This may be even more clear.

```
if(objectToCheck != null){
 // objectToCheck can be used
}else{
 // Handle the case when objectToCheck is null 
}
```